# How do you implement a google-like calendar in javaFX and scenebuilder?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I am looking to implement an agenda/google type calendar using JavaFX in netbeans and scene builder. I cannot seem to get the JFXtras Agenda sample working, I keep getting import errors. Have browsed for quite a while and have not got any closer to get it working.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What import errors? Have you included the JFXtras libraries in your classpath?

Comment: I downloaded the JFXtras-agenda jar files and included them in my libraries. The import error occurs for:
import jfxtras.labs.samples.JFXtrasLabsSampleBase;
import jfxtras.scene.control.CalendarTextField;
import jfxtras.scene.layout.GridPane;

It says they do not exist